# Is there a better way to write out this long 'or' statement?

Tags: python

i always feel it's so messy when i write something like this:

```
if (subject == 'a') or (subject == 'e') or (subject == 'i') or (subject == 'o') or (subject == 'u'):
```

Is there not a better way to write this that would not require loads of or's or a loop?

Comment: `if subject in 'aeiou':`

Comment: @muddyfish Not entirely equal, it will also match multiple characters, but `if subject in list('aeiou'):` won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write it out like this

```
if subject in 'aeiou':
```

This works because `str` supports the `in` operator with characters and substrings.

Note this will allow through things like `ae`, `aeiou` and other substrings.

```
if subject in tuple('aeiou'):
```

OR

```
if subject in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
```

might be better depending on your situation

Comment: Out of interest (I'm not a python expert), does this emit subject being, say "ae"?

Comment: @Bathsheba no it doesn't

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Is there anything that python *can't* do?

Comment: @Bathsheba computationally impossible problems. Other than that, it's a bit broad :)

Comment: @Slayther Not with that attitude. I'm sure it would if you asked nicely

Comment: @Farhan.K Oh, I forgot the DoTheDishes module